# before each component render how to check if user is loggedIn or not in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am newbie to React, On each component render i want to check whether user is loggedIn or not ? so that i can change my headers and component according to that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as props to your component. Assuming that you're using redux, you can change the global state when user logs in.
In your reducer:

```
case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    isLoggedIn: true
});
```

You can now pass the logged in state(isLoggedIn) to your component from your container using react-redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loggedIn: state.yourReducer.isLoggedIn
});
const HeaderContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

In your Header component there will be loggedIn prop that you can able to use in your render function.

Comment: Thanks for your help @kosker